# Annoying auto-formatting occurring in WPF TextBox databound to Double property

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

I've got a TextBox that is driving me insane with the way it is auto-formatting itself as I enter numbers.

For example, I want to enter -0.00004, but as I type, the TextBox removes the negative sign as soon as I type the first <kbd>0</kbd>.

I then tried -.00004, which doesn't remove the negative sign when I type <kbd>.</kbd>, but then as soon as I press <kbd>0</kbd> it removes the `-` and `.`.

The only way I've been able to get the TextBox to behave is to enter `0.00004` first, which it then autoformats to `4E-05`, then add the negative sign to the front.  Or I can enter `-4E-5`, which it then autoformats to `-4E-05`, which is fine, but if I enter `-4E-05` the `E` gets dropped as soon as I press <kbd>0</kbd>.

What I'm hoping for is a way to disable this behavior with a built-in property of some kind, but if it does not exist, writing an `IValueConverter` might be my only option.

Comment: Are you setting the `StringFormat` property, or using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around the auto-formatting is to use an `IValueConverter` on the bound double property. You will need to add logic to the `Convert` method to convert from a double to a string and the `ConvertBack` method to convert from a string to a double. Here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with an example.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource NumToStrConverter}}"/>
```

Another way would be to set the `StringFormat` on the Binding to a number with the number of decimal places to show. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for other formats.

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Number, StringFormat=N10}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping that there was some way to either completely disable it or change settings, something that is built-in and doesn't require the `IValueConverter`.  But as I already have IValueConverters available, I can totally do that.  I should have specified my goal in my question, which I will update now.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!  I had no idea that StringFormat even existed!

Comment: I think I am happy with the StringFormat + removal of the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute.  This works for me, thank you.