# How can I make a WPF TextBox care about a decimal point?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

So I have a `TextBox` that only allows numbers and decimal points. I want the user to only be allowed to enter 1 decimal point.

Here is the code that is triggered on the `PreviewTextInput` event: (Some of the code is a little redundant, but it does the job)

```
    private void PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

        if (e.Text == ".")
        {

            if (textBox.Text.Contains("."))
            {

                e.Handled = true;
                return;

            }

            else
            {
                //Here I am attempting to add the decimal point myself
                textBox.Text = (textBox.Text + ".");
                e.handled = true;
                return;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);
            return;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+"); //regex that matches disallowed text
        return !regex.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

**The problem is** that the first decimal point that is entered is not "*significant*" until it is followed by a number. So, if the user enters `123.` and you were to set a `breakpoint` and check the value of `textBox.text` it would be `123`. I know this is happening because the `textBox` is bound to a `Double` so it is trying to be "smart" and forget about those currently "insignificant" values (The ".").

There shouldn't be anything wrong with my code, I was just hoping to force the `textBox` to hopefully skip over some unnecessary(?) auto-formatting.

*Is there a way to make the `textBox` "care" about that first decimal point?*

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482240/annoying-auto-formatting-occurring-in-wpf-textbox-databound-to-double-property) that was never answered.

**or**

*Is there a different approach to limiting the number of decimals?" (I have done a lot of research in this area, and I don't think there are any other options.)

Comment: possible different approach: allow the users to enter any number of decimals, then upon submitting input (depending on your settings this is upon pressing the enter key or when focus is lost) parse the double, format it back into a string with only one decimal and set the textbox value to that string

Comment: @stijn This will work for the `TextBox` but I also have a `DataGrid` that causes the program to crash with illegal data. (This is a well known bug with `DataGrids`) I will give it a shot and see if I can get it to work for the `DataGrid`. I know though if I can just completely prevent the user from entering multiple decimals, then everything would be great.

Comment: As an alternative, you may check if the text can be converted to decimal or not. If yes format it for decimal and commas using String.ToString(). If no, replace it with "0.0" or force the user to correct the input before leaving the textbox. I personally use this approach.

Comment: I don't know your application context, but I'd warn you about localization. There are countries where . is used as a thousand separator and , is the decimal one...

Answer (score 0):

if just limiting the charcters you want maybe something like binding with the string format would meet your needs

[here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) is a good example of the format for double

And this would be an example of doing the binding in code to your ViewModel

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding LimitedDouble,StringFormat={}{0:00.00}}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: This seems to be a little un-intuitive and looks like it may frustrate my users a bit.

Comment: When I implemented that code in the XAML it was very easy to break. I was able to enter several decimal points. The user does not need to change the format, but this code is not very strong.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtDecimal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b' && e.KeyChar!='.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDecimal.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the current culture uses a different decimal seperator than '.'. I guess you have to substitute it the '.' to  `Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);`